# Kivy Updating text with color from Python

Tags: python, button, label, kivy

Can someone please show me how to correctly update the color of text in a label/button in Kivy with Python?

I want to be able to change the color, the user guide suggests markup language but I've tried and just can't get it to work. Ultimately I want to change the color of the text at different times of day - I can code that bit its just the changing of the text color outside of Kivy language?

I've extracted the following from my code as the relevant (I hope!) bits that i need the guidance on ..

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta



Builder.load_string('''
<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    the_time: _id_lbl_time
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: _id_lbl_time
            text: 'Time'
            font_size: 120
''')


class MainScreen(Screen):
    def update_time(self, sec):
      MyTime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
      self.the_time.text = MyTime <--- UPDATE COLOR HERE?

class ScreenManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
      self.main_screen = MainScreen()
      return self.main_screen

    def on_start(self):
      Clock.schedule_interval(self.main_screen.update_time, 1)             
#===========================================================

# run the App !
ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code a bit, to make it change to a random color.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import random


Builder.load_string('''
<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    the_time: _id_lbl_time
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            color: root.color
            id: _id_lbl_time
            text: 'Time'
            font_size: 120
''')


class MainScreen(Screen):

    color = ListProperty([1,1,1,1])

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MainScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_time, 1)

    def update_time(self, sec):
      MyTime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
      self.the_time.text = MyTime
      self.color = [random(), random(), random(), 1]



class ScreenManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
      self.main_screen = MainScreen()
      return self.main_screen


ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

Comment: Yep thats working now - Thanks and very very festive! I was very close to solving then as I did try ListProperty, I just had the `color = ListProperty` in the Kivy code and not the main class.

Comment: @northwarks np, yes looks nice :)